# Find root without while and for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

The program I'm coding should find the root of a given double.

The condition is: you're not allowed to use while and for loops. any kind of loops are not allowed.

Our professor said it's forbidden to use the `stdlib` function `sqrt()`.

I started to code but it's still not working. hope anyone can help.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

double mysqrt(double a, double b, double c);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double dBegin{0};
    double dOldroot{0};
    double dNewroot{0};
    double a{0};1

    cin >> dBegin;
    dOldroot = dBegin;
    mysqrt(a, dOldroot, dNewroot);
    cout << dNewroot;
    return 0;
}

double mysqrt(double a, double b, double c) {
    c = (b + (a / b)) / 2.0;
    if (a != 8) {
        c = mysqrt(a++, b, c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: "its forbidden to use the stdlib function sqrt" Then, how about using `sqrtl()`?

Comment: Hint: [Newton's method - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: related link : https://www.careercup.com/question?id=6657802751705088

Comment: Can we use recursion instead of while or for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Newton-Raphson's Method** to find out the square-root of a given number `num` *(in my code)*.

You may find this video link useful: [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2158QbsunA8). Using this algorithm i've solved this problem.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* we are gonna use Newton-Raphson's method to find its square because 
   it converges quickly, even calculators use this algo. to find the sqr-root */

double find_sqrt(double x, int num, int count) {
    if(count == 0) 
        return x;

    double f_x  = x*x - num;
    double f_dx = 2*x;
    double res = x - (f_x/f_dx);

    x = find_sqrt(res, num, count -1);
    return x;

}

int main() {
    double num;
    cin >> num;

    /* Here 20 is the maximum number of times it will run and 
    num/2 is the random number send to the function between the range 1 to num */
    cout << find_sqrt(num/2, num, 20);  

    return 0;
}
```

The result might not be much precise but it will always be almost near to the actual square-root of the number.
**Reason:** Floating-precision error. You must be knowing about this i believe.

Comment: Mind it. this code will fail if `num = 0`. So please be aware of it

Answer (score 0):

- You have junk `1` to cause compile error after `double a{0};`
- Your code will do infinite recursion because the first argument won't updated. Using `double` for counter isn't also a good idea.
- You are throwing away the value returned from `mysqrt` in `main()`.
- Using arguments as local variables without reading its value isn't a good idea.

Fixing these errors, your code will be like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double mysqrt(int a, double b);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double dBegin{0};
    double dOldroot{0};
    double dNewroot{0};
    int a{0};

    cin >> dBegin;
    dOldroot = dBegin;

    dNewroot = mysqrt(a, dOldroot);

    cout << dNewroot;

    return 0;
}

double mysqrt(int a, double b) {
    double c = (b + (a / b)) / 2.0;
    if (a != 8) {
        c = mysqrt(a + 1, b);
    }
    return c;
}
```

This code failed to calculate square root, but compiled and exited soon when ran.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What should i exactly change to get the right square root?